# Heroku Deployment Failure - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: heroku, next.js

The full stack trace here:

https://pastebin.com/4sPgfuee

But a couple snippets:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.exports.useContext (/tmp/build_758b0112/frontend/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/tmp/build_758b0112/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js:202:34)
    at Wc (/tmp/build_758b0112/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)    

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.exports.useContext (/tmp/build_758b0112/frontend/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at Head (/tmp/build_758b0112/frontend/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js:202:34)
```

Does anyone know what this error means? I don't use useContext anywhere in my code. I was told it was an issue with the Image and Head tags in Next JS, and so I swapped them for  and  tags in my code respectively and got the same errors. I removed react-dom as one of my dependencies and it still gives this error. The project works on my local machine no problem. How do I get rid of this error?

Thinking about it a bit more, admittedly, the frontend folder I want to deploy to github isn't in the root of my project. But I found a work around where I have a copy of node_modules/ and my package.json file in the root where the package.json file is identical to the one in my front end except for this small feature:

EDIT: adjusted for full package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "cd frontend ; next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "next": "^12.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.15",
    "web3": "^1.7.4",
    "web3-utils": "^1.7.4"
  }
}
```

Within my scripts section, I inserted the cd frontend command to get to the frontend folder to build the project. Could this have backfired on me?

EDIT: When I run `npm run build` on my machine from the frontend folder, I get

```
:frontend$ npm run build

> frontend@0.1.0 build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from ~/Project/frontend/.env.local

./pages/ResplendentCard.js
39:22  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
39:22  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
(node:33657) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (5/5)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      5.76 kB        83.3 kB
├   └ css/149b18973e5508c7.css             655 B
├   /_app                                  0 B            77.6 kB
├ ○ /404                                   195 B          77.8 kB
├ λ /api/hello                             0 B            77.6 kB
├ ○ /resplendent (480 ms)                  4.59 kB         875 kB
├   ├ css/0de6f3d7089795f1.css             27.4 kB
├   └ css/0a7d2580efac90af.css             202 B
└ ○ /ResplendentCard (436 ms)              217 B           870 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              77.6 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-45405dbdcddf505d.js   45.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-43f32a18558cfd50.js        30.9 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-8027895d08fe9881.js  510 B
  ├ chunks/webpack-f9a9a24bf6cd9a1b.js     897 B
  └ css/179c343107565a9c.css               478 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

I assume this means it works. Yet when I run the build command from my root folder:

```
> frontend@0.1.0 build
> cd frontend ; next build

info  - Loaded env from ~Project/frontend/.env.local

./pages/ResplendentCard.js
39:22  Warning: Do not use <img>. Use Image from 'next/image' instead. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
39:22  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
(node:33746) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data ...node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

Error: Cannot find module '../frontend/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/constants.js'
Require stack:
- ~Project/frontend/.next/server/pages/_document.js
- ~Project/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- ~Project/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- ~Project/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- ~Project/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
- ~Project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.221 (~Project/frontend/.next/server/pages/_document.js:32:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (~Project/frontend/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.105 (~Project/frontend/.next/server/chunks/105.js:375:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (~Project/frontend/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (~Project/frontend/.next/server/pages/_document.js:70:39)
    at ~~Project/frontend/.next/server/pages/_document.js:71:70 {
  type: 'Error',
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '~Project/frontend/.next/server/pages/_document.js',
    '~Project/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '~Project/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '~Project/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '~Project/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js',
    '~Project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v17.2.0
```

Comment: Your `package.json` shows absolutely no dependency. In case you removed it: Provide it and show the build (not application) log that the project is correctly installed. The error shows you have a problem with the dependencies.